# If a class is next to another element with a specific class, have special CSS, just CSS without JS

Tags: css

I have this scenario:

```
<body>    
<section>
    <div class="random name">
        <div class="random name">
            <div class="random name">
              <div class="random name">
                 <h2 class="title"></h2>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="random name">
    <div class="random name">
        <div class="random name">
            <div class="random name">
              <div class="random name">
                 <span class="music"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="album">
              <div class="random name">
                 <div class="pop rock"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Now, if the `div` has two classes, `rock and pop`, if this `div` has the `rock` class, give the desired style to the `span` with the `music` class and the `h2` tag with the `title` class, for example, the background color should be `red`, otherwise, if the `div` does not have the `rock` class and only the class `pop`, the background color of `span` and `h2` should be `blue`.

`divs` that have a `random name` class means that they do not have a fixed name class and it changes dynamically!

Comment: you could try using `has` but you would have to have a common class ancestor for the music and rock pop div rather than a load of randoms - https://jsfiddle.net/mcd9otjp/

Comment: Have you considered applying some rules, or specific `class`, `id`, or `data-*` rules to your generated html? Possible semantic, predictable html in which to group the various pieces of information?

Comment: @Pete not sure it _needs_ such an ancestor class, the child combinator works within :has() as well. `:has(> div > div > .rock.pop) .music` gets the same result in your example; although I have not yet checked if it might need further modifications to cover all possible cases.

Comment: it's a bit dirty though @Cbroe - best to use classes where available rather than having such bad code that is hard to maintain and so brittle

Comment: @Pete agree on that; and creating different HTML to begin with - or at least "enrich" it with more information in relevant places, as David is suggesting - would probably make the most sense here, if at all possible. (I'm guessing that HTML is probably built based on a dynamic data source, and did not get put into the page "static".)

Comment: @CBroe, Exactly, it is not possible to change the html and these changes should only be applied with css

Comment: _"not worked for me (https://jsfiddle.net/mcd9otjp )"_ - the text "not blue" _is_ still not blue, the text "blue" _is_ blue ... (and it appears to fulfill the given requirements aside from the visual aspect, text == text color, as well) - so how exactly is this "not working" now?

Comment: @Pete, Thank you, what should be done if the ancestors of the classes are not common?
In the same example you gave, is there a way other than changing the html?

Comment: @Pete,It means that the style of the `h2 tag` should also change with the `title` class

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is Pete's answer.
Anyway, you can get help from body to solve your problem.

```
body:has(.pop.rock) .title {
  color: blue;
  background: red;
}

div:has(.pop.rock) .music {
  color: blue;
  background: red;
}
```

I tested it and there was no problem.
I hope I was able to help.

**Preview:**

```css
body:has(.pop.rock) .title {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

div:has(.pop.rock) .music {
  color: blue;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

  <section>
      <div class="random name">
          <div class="random name">
              <div class="random name">
                <div class="random name">
                   <h2 class="title">Test Title</h2>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </section>

  <div class="random name">
      <div class="random name">
          <div class="random name">
              <div class="random name">
                <div class="random name">
                   <span class="music">MUSIC</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="album">
                <div class="random name">
                   <div class="pop rock"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to you and pete and everyone else, my problem is solved.

Comment: I'm currently on my phone, and don't have a way of testing this, but `body:has(.pop.rock) body .title` looks like it shouldn't work, since it seems to require a nested `<body>` element?

Comment: @DavidThomas I had added an extra body by mistake, thank you, it was edited and the preview of the codes was also included.